# XUnit.net: run Theories in parallel

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

xunit.net supports parallel test execution.

My tests are parameterized (theories). Every test I run against different storage. Here's an example:

```
public class TestCase1
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("mssql")]
    [InlineData("oracle")]
    [InlineData("pgsql")]
    [InlineData("sqlite")]
    public void DoTests(string storage) {}
}
public class TestCase2
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("mssql")]
    [InlineData("oracle")]
    [InlineData("pgsql")]
    [InlineData("sqlite")]
    public void DoTests(string storage) {}
}
```

By default all tests are executed [in parallel](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html). By they can be grouped in Collections (with help of `Collection` attribute).

I can't run all tests in parallel as every test case has it own db schema. So I put all tests into a single collection with assembly-level attribute:

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(CollectionBehavior.CollectionPerAssembly)]
```

But it also means that tests for differnt storages are also run serially.

What I want is to run tests for different storages in parallel but for single storage in serial:

=> TestCase1.DoTest("mssql") => TestCase2.DoTest("mssql")
=> TestCase1.DoTest("oracle") => TestCase2.DoTest("oracle")
and so on

Is it possible in xunit.net?

UPDATE:
(put it here as SO doesn't support code in comments).
As @BradWilson suggested, it's possible to split tests with derived classes:

```
public class TestCase1
{
    public void DoTests(string storage) {}
}
public class TestCase1_MSSQL
{
    [Fact]
    public void DoTests(string storage) 
    {
        DoTests("mssql");
    }
}
public class TestCase1_Oracle
{
    [Fact]
    public void DoTests(string storage) 
    {
        DoTests("oracle");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with theories and inline data; instead, I would do it with an abstract base class and concrete test classes for each storage method. That gets you the grouping you want.

Comment: Ok, makes sence. But I'll have to repeat all methods (calling to base) for all storages (see update in the question).
It's a bit cumbersome... but should work, thanks.